# Pass any .txt file to existing AppleScript using Automator

Tags: macos, applescript

I currently have an AppleScript that reads a hardcoded plain text file, which contains a long list, into a variable, which is then read into another variable as paragraphs. The script works very well for my purposes. This is basically what I am using:

```
set fileHandler to (read POSIX file "/path/to/my/file.txt")
set newList to paragraphs of fileHandler

repeat with i in newList
     # do stuff
end repeat
```

The omitted script opens a Safari location, invokes JavaScript using `i` as a variable on that page, writes the result to a new plain text file, closes the Safari window, then repeats. It continues until it reaches the end of the list, then outside the `repeat` runs a `do shell script` that cleans up the new text file a bit.

The trouble is that every time I want to run the script using a different list, I have to open the hardcoded file and paste in the list. I'd rather just drop any .txt file on to an Automator application that wraps around my current script.

I've tried to use "Combine Text Files" and I feel like I get pretty close but I can't quite pass in the contents of the .txt file the way I'd like. I can't pass it in the same, unless I am doing something wrong with it. And "Get Value of Variable"/"Set Value of Variable" add on an extra "Text" item to my list, which I don't understand.

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
set fileHandler to (read POSIX file arg) -- the dropped text file
set newList to paragraphs of fileHandler

repeat with i in newList
     # do stuff
end repeat
```

...but it doesn't work that way, unfortunately.

I'd really rather not reinvent a whole new script if I can help it. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automator is actually not needed. Save this code in Script Editor as application (bundle) and drop files onto it.

```
on open theFiles
  repeat with aFile in theFiles
    set newList to paragraphs of (read aFile)

    repeat with i in newList
        # do stuff
    end repeat
  end repeat
end open
```

Comment: ;) I knew I was missing something simple... Thanks.